# Whenever I type colon in insert mode it moves my text to the very beginning of line

Tags: vim

Whenever I type a : (colon) it moves all the text on the current line to the beginning of the line, ignoring spaces and tabs.

So if I type

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  typeAhead //I'm about to type a colon, but right now it looks fine
})
```

Then I type the colon it moves the text and it now looks like

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
typeAhead: //text is no longer indented
})
```

This is a javascript file, so that might be causing the problem?

How can I stop my text from being moved to the beginning of the line when I type a colon?

Comment: You've mapped the `:` character to some command. Does the problem continue if you quite and restart the editor? Check your `.vimrc`.

Comment: what is the output of `:verbose imap :`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a colon to the end of a token is causing vim to interpret it as a jump label for C-indenting purposes.  `:set cino+=L0` should cause it to stay in the current column.

Also, doesn't the JSON syntax allow you to quote the thing that precedes the colon?  That should prevent vim from thinking it's a label too.

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    "typeAhead": "foo"  // this isn't a jump label
});
```

Comment: Or use `:setlocal autoindent`, as the `cindent` isn't particularly well suited to JavaScript, anyway.

Comment: @IngoKarkat it works well enough. And at least it recognizes braces :)